# Looking for modern english texts in public domain / CC-BY-SA

Tags: data-request, english, corpora, creative-commons, books

Is there a library of public domain / CC-BY-SA english texts, written later than 1990? I need it to build a corpora with links to full texts, which isn't possible with copyrighted material. At the same time I would like this corpora to be up-to-date with current state of the language.

Comment: Literature, or just English language text?

Comment: @philshem any kind of text, not necessary literature, but I wish I would find mixed content: literature, news, articles, etc to build complete and precise corpora

Answer (score 3):

Some ideas coming to my mind:

- Wikibooks
- Wikipedia (dump)
- other specialised wikis, e.g. for cooking recipes
- fan fiction sites
- obvious, but you may overlook it: The content of the stack exchange sites (Science Fiction and World Building may be of special interest to you)

Comment: Great list and the last item in particular, tnx!

Answer (score 2):

[Arxiv.org](http://arxiv.org/) is a repository of scientific pre-prints.

- [License](https://arxiv.org/help/license)
- [API](http://arxiv.org/help/api/index)
- [Bulk data access](http://arxiv.org/help/bulk_data)

[image]

Many papers can be accessed in [TeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX) typesetting format (in addition to PDF, PS).